# Как должен выглядеть адрес сайта с поддержкой IPv6?

Tags: tcp-ip

Добрый день, уважаемые!

Мучаюсь вопросом: есть, скажем, у меня сайт, и есть желание сделать его доступным и по IPv6. Так вот правильнее (точнее, удобнее для пользоваталей) будет привязать AAAA-запись к тому же доменному имени, что и для IPv4 работает, или же завести еще одно имя, именно для доступа по IPv6?

Пример: имеем сайт [www.lazurit.com](http://www.lazurit.com/), доступный только по IPv4. Чтобы порадовать посетителей, что сделать:

1. просто прописываем его IPv6-адрес **в добавок** к IPv4-адресу к имени **www**.lazurit.com, 
   *или*
2. заводим какое-нибудь имя **w6**.lazurit.com для доступа по IPv6, а по адресу www... оставляем только IPv4-доступ?

Вопрос не праздный, наскольковижу, в мире кне все безоблачно с поддержкой IPv6, и кое-где, хоть поддержка и заявлена, доступ по этому протоколу фактически глючит или очень медленный. Т.ч. вариант 1 вроде как может создать проблемы вплоть до неоткрытия сайта у конкретного посетителя. Вариант же 2, получается, только для техноманьяков, ибо простой посетитель вряд ли будет думать над такими мелочами...

Посоветуйте, как поступить?

Comment: А какой демон стоит? К примеру: у nginx вроде можно проксировать с любыми условиями. К примеру там же и поддержк определить. Для пользователей неявно будет. А техноманьяки с настроенным ипв6 как раз туда и будут попадать.

Comment: Так проксируй или нет, а на имя-то какое должен демон отзываться?

Comment: Имя одно будет. внутри спроксируешь.

Comment: Т.е. ответ на мой вопрос - делать таки одно имя и для IPv4, и для IPv6?

Answer (score 3):

Я бы пошел в две ступени:

1. Сначала Ваш первый вариант, ipv6.example.com с A+AAAA, www.example.com только с A-записью. Если на сайте есть сообщество — объявляется, активисты-волонтеры идут, проверяют, докладывают (нужна удобная формочка отчета в две кнопки «работает/не работает» и опциональными комментариями).

   Если вариант с тестерами-волонтерами по какой-либо причине не подходит — еще одна возможная альтернатива — повесить на www.example.com «невидимый» iframe на некий A+AAAA ipv6test.example.com и изучить в логах как оно будет работать — какой процент пользователей «потеряется». Опять же, для скрытия проблем можно много что придумать — например, JavaScript'ом по таймауту удалять «зависший» iframe, чтобы, если уж все не заработало — оно не заставляло браузер висеть в состоянии «грузим» и не смущало пользователей дольше нескольких секунд.
2. Затем, когда будет видно, насколько много вылезло проблем и как их решать — делать по-правильному, один example.com (с опциональным www. — как сочтете каноничным) с A и AAAA-записями. Собственно, по идее — правильно именно так, но раз у Вас сомнения в том, не создаст ли это проблем — стоит заранее взять и проверить. Тестировать поведение браузеров можно на себе, выводя лично себе iframe на некий, намеренно не отвечающий ни на что (т.е. чтобы никаких TCP RST или ICMP port unreachable) broken.example.com.

Почему первый вариант годится только временно, для тестов? Потому что никто не будет долго ходить по этому адресу, и вся его пригодность — только для временного тестирования.